# How to send file using third argument in Python Socket?

Tags: python, sockets, serversocket, python-sockets

I'm just new to Python Socket~

I'm making a socket project which can send a file to the server, and I would like to make to client execution like so:

python client.py [hostname] [port] [send filename]

*sys.argv[1]*,  *sys.argv[2]* are used to send hostname & port to the socket.recv(), but how can the server recognise the filename/third argument?

Comment: You cannot send "files". You only can send data, i.e. bytes. These data need to contain the content of the file. If you want to make the server aware of the original filename you need to send the filename too as data.

Comment: it's fixed :) thanks~

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you how but one thing:

> There isn't code shown which you tried. In code I mean `Python` script.

In `socket` module there is option to send files, called `socket.sendfile(file, offset=0, count=None)` and it is option to send files via `socket`.

See documention for more details.

Latest stable 3x (3.8) [Click Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html)

Latest stable 2x (2.7) [Click Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)